# How to install SSL certificate locally for logging into Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

**Operating System** installed is **Centos** Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core). I have installed **PCF** (Pivotal Cloud Foundry) locally on my pc. I'm trying to install a SSL certificate by using command `cf dev trust` and output of this command is:

> *Error: failed to trust VM certificates: failed to open file: open /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt: permission denied.*

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you try running as root or with sudo?  It looks like the command is trying to access a file to which it does not have access.  Alternatively, give your current user access to read/write that file.  Whatever is needed by your command.

Comment: @DanielMikusa I have tried with sudo, but still it didn't work as expected. The owner of file is root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and here is how I got it to work.

**`sudo setfacl -m u:[USERNAME]:rw /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`**

I just changed permission to rw of the certificate for the user and just

**`cf dev trust`**

got it to work.